# find 2^n -2 combinations of elements in a list

Tags: python, list, combinations, apriori

I have the following list:

```
list1 = ['g1','g2','g3','g4']
```

I want to find `2^n-2` combinations where `n` is the total number of items in the list. For `n = 4` the result should be `2^4 -2 = 14`, i.e. 14 combinations.

The combinations are:

```
[[['g1'],['g2','g3','g4']],[['g2'],['g1','g3','g4']], [['g3'],['g1','g2','g4']],['g4'],['g1','g2','g3']],[['g1','g2'],['g3','g4']],[['g1','g3'],['g2','g4']],[['g1','g4'],['g3','g4']],[['g2','g3'],['g1','g4']],
[['g2','g4'],['g1','g3']],[['g3','g4'],['g1','g2']],[['g1','g2','g3'],['g4']],[['g2','g3','g4'],['g1']],[['g3','g4','g1'],['g2']],[['g4','g1','g2'],['g3']]]
```

I know one approach:
in first iteration take single element and put it into a list and other elements in second list: `['g1'],['g2','g3','g4']`
in second iteration take 2 elements in a list and other elements in second list. `['g1','g2'],['g1','g4']`
Is there any other approach ?? 
I'm writing this program in python.
My approach is costly. Is there any library method to do this quickly.

Comment: What do you mean by costly? The algorithmic complexity of generating the combinations would be exponential regardless of the implementation.

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect your requirements better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a functional approach using `itertools`

```
import itertools as iter

list1 = ['g1', 'g2', 'g3', 'g4']
combinations = [iter.combinations(list1, n) for n in range(1, len(list1))]
flat_combinations = iter.chain.from_iterable(combinations)
result = map(lambda x: [list(x), list(set(list1) - set(x))], flat_combinations)
# [[['g1'], ['g4', 'g3', 'g2']], [['g2'], ['g4', 'g3', 'g1']], [['g3'], ['g4', 'g2', 'g1']],...
len(result)
# 14
```

Comment: How do you get the second part of the tuple?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure that's needed from the slightly confusing question. He's after the combinations, which are only the first parts of the tuples.

Comment: OP's example is a list of ordered set partitions with exactly 2 parts. This only generates half of each partition. You need to pair each subset/combination with its complement.

Comment: I believe the question asks for number of possible pairs. So this answer may be part of a full solution; or there might a better solution.

Comment: @hyades I added that now.

Comment: Glad to hear that @SourasekharBanerjee! :)

Answer (score 2):

> itertools.combinations(iterable, r)
>
> Return r length subsequences of elements from the input iterable.
>   Combinations are emitted in lexicographic sort order. So, if the input
>   iterable is sorted, the combination tuples will be produced in sorted
>   order.

```
from itertools import combinations
list1 = ['g1','g2','g3','g4']
for n in range(1,len(list1)):
    for i in combinations(list1,n):
        print(set(i), set(list1) - set(i))
```

out:

```
{'g1'} {'g2', 'g3', 'g4'}
{'g2'} {'g1', 'g3', 'g4'}
{'g3'} {'g1', 'g2', 'g4'}
{'g4'} {'g1', 'g2', 'g3'}
{'g1', 'g2'} {'g3', 'g4'}
{'g1', 'g3'} {'g2', 'g4'}
{'g1', 'g4'} {'g2', 'g3'}
{'g2', 'g3'} {'g1', 'g4'}
{'g2', 'g4'} {'g1', 'g3'}
{'g3', 'g4'} {'g1', 'g2'}
{'g1', 'g2', 'g3'} {'g4'}
{'g1', 'g2', 'g4'} {'g3'}
{'g1', 'g3', 'g4'} {'g2'}
{'g2', 'g3', 'g4'} {'g1'}
```

you can try this

Comment: This is pretty much the same as my answer, and not taking into account that OP wants all combinations of length 1 up to `len(list1)`.

Comment: just iter over it, that's very simple

Comment: see the op of my question. Here I don't need all nC2 element what I need is first element in one list or tuple and other elements in second list or tuple. ('g1'),('g2','g3','g4') in second iteration I want ('g1','g2'),('g3','g4') etc.

Comment: @宏杰李 It is very simple indeed I already posted an answer doing just that.

Answer (score 0):

I like the solution from the Chinese coder (I guess). Here's my own solution:

```
import itertools


def flatten(*z):
    return z


list1 = ['g1','g2','g3','g4']

sublists = []
for i in range(1, len(list1)):
    sublists.extend(itertools.combinations(list1, i))

pairs = []
for a, b in itertools.product(sublists, sublists):
    if len(a) + len(b) == len(list1) and \
    len(set(flatten(*a, *b))) == len(list1):
        pairs.append((a, b))

print(pairs, len(pairs))
```

Comment: Since you materialized the powerset (minus the empty and whole set) as a list, you can just `zip` it with the reverse of itself: like `pairs = list(zip(sublists, reversed(sublists)))` instead of using `itertools.product` and filtering.