# All possibilities to split a list into two lists

Tags: python, list, combinations, permutation

I have a list with some elements and want to iterate over all possible ways to divide this list into two lists. By that I mean all combinations, so the order doesn't matter (i.e. Element 1 and 3 could be in the one list and Element 2 in the other). Currently I do it like this, where `facs` is my initial list:

```
patterns = []
for i in range(2**(len(facs)-1)):
    pattern = []
    for j in range((len(facs)-1)):
        pattern.append(i//(2**j)%2)
    patterns.append(pattern)

for pattern in patterns:
    l1 = [facs[-1]]
    l2 = []
    for i in range(len(pattern)):
        if pattern[i] == 1:
            l1.append(facs[i])
        else:
            l2.append(facs[i])
```

So I basically create a list of length `2^(len(facs)-1)` and fill it with every possible combination of ones and zeros. I then 'overlay' every pattern with `facs`, except for the last element of `facs` which is always in `l1`, as I'd otherwise get every result twice, as I handle two lists the same, no matter what lists is `l1` or `l2`.

Is there a faster and more elegant (shorter/more pythonic) way to do this?

Comment: Saw this answer ? [enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/752308/split-list-into-smaller-lists)

Comment: What do you mean by all possible ways? Permutations, combinations, or splitting the list maintain the order of element?

Comment: @IssamElyazidi Yes, I saw that thread. Doesn't answer my question tho.

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri I mean permutations. I'll add that do the post.

Comment: Permutations means the order _matters_. You probably want all combinations. In other words, you're treating your list like sets.

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40158243/6732794) [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40670740/6732794) for future reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) has `product()` which could be used to generate the masks and `izip()` which could combine the lists for easy filtering. As a bonus, since they return iterators, they don't use much memory.

```
from itertools import *

facs = ['one','two','three']

l1 = []
l2 = []
for pattern in product([True,False],repeat=len(facs)):
    l1.append([x[1] for x in izip(pattern,facs) if x[0]])
    l2.append([x[1] for x in izip(pattern,facs) if not x[0]])
```

Comment: @PattuX It occurs to me that both lists (`l1` and `l2`) would have the same list of sets just in different orders.

Comment: Just create them as tuples in a single list.

Answer (score 3):

Just extending @Ouroborus solution using `filter`s and keeping the results together:

```
import itertools as it

# itertools recipe
def partition(pred, iterable):
    t1, t2 = it.tee(iterable)
    return it.filterfalse(pred, t1), filter(pred, t2)

>>> facs = ['one','two','three']
>>> [[[x[1] for x in f] for f in partition(lambda x: x[0], zip(pattern, facs))]
...  for pattern in product([True, False], repeat=len(facs))]
[[[], ['one', 'two', 'three']],
 [['three'], ['one', 'two']],
 [['two'], ['one', 'three']],
 [['two', 'three'], ['one']],
 [['one'], ['two', 'three']],
 [['one', 'three'], ['two']],
 [['one', 'two'], ['three']],
 [['one', 'two', 'three'], []]]
```

Comment: What if I don't want empty subset?

Comment: Just add a guard `if f` after the `partition()`call.

Answer (score 2):

First part may be one-lined with nested list comprehensions like this:

```
patterns = [ [ i//(2**j)%2 for j in range(len(facs)-1) ] for i in range(2**(len(facs)-1)) ]
```

For the second part, you cannot do a list comprehension since there are 2 lists, but you can do a ternary expression to select the list to append to.

And you can `zip` both `pattern` and `facs` lists to avoid playing with indexes:

```
for pattern in patterns:
    l1 = [facs[-1]]
    l2 = []
    for fac,pat in zip(facs,pattern):
        (l1 if pat == 1 else l2).append(fac)
```

of course you have to use `l1` and `l2` during the iteration, because you reset them each time.

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, you can also [fold the powerset in half](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40166673/6732794) to produce the desired results. For example, consider the powerset of `{A, B, C}` in colexicographic order according to each subset's corresponding bitmask:

```
{}, {A}, {B}, {A, B} | {C}, {A, C}, {B, C}, {A, B, C}
```

If you rotate the first half clockwise by 90 degrees, and rotate the second half counterclockwise by 90 degrees, and then line them up, you have two columns of subsets and each row forms a partition of the original set. We can implement this "folding" by zipping the powerset with the reverse of itself and taking half of the generated pairs of subsets. Taking half ensures that only unique partitions are produced (e.g. `[['two', 'three'], ['one']]` and `[['one'], ['two', 'three']]` are the same partition), assuming the original sequence is itself distinct.

```
import itertools

def binary_splits(a):
    partitions = zip(powerset_colex(a), powerset_colex(a, reverse = True))
    return itertools.islice(partitions, 1 << len(a) >> 1)

def powerset_colex(a, reverse = False):
    n = len(a)
    bitmasks = range(1 << n)[::-1] if reverse else range(1 << n)
    return (list(itertools.compress(a, iter_bits(bits, n))) for bits in bitmasks)

def iter_bits(n, k):
    return (n >> i & 1 for i in range(k))
```

While it's not very useful, it makes for a cute solution. Here's a couple of  variations that--instead of running two powerset iterators in reverse--just directly generate the complement for each subset.

```
def binary_splits_1(a):
    n = len(a)

    for bitmask in range(1 << n >> 1):
        subset     = itertools.compress(a, iter_bits(+bitmask, n))
        complement = itertools.compress(a, iter_bits(~bitmask, n))
        yield list(subset), list(complement)

def binary_splits_2(a):
    n = len(a)

    def dual_compress(items, bitmask):
        buckets = [], []

        for item, bit in zip(items, iter_bits(bitmask, n)):
            buckets[1 - bit].append(item)

        return buckets

    return (dual_compress(a, bitmask) for bitmask in range(1 << n >> 1))
```