# Divide list elements into sub-lists of unique combinations

Tags: python-3.x

I need all the possible unique combinations of the elements of a list when divided into two sublists.

For example - if I have a list:
[1, 2, 3] 
and I wanna divide it into two sublists, like the following:

[1], [2,3]

[1,2], [3]

[2], [1,3]

Now how would I find out all these unique combinations,
Also, the order of the elements is neglected here.

Comment: Have you attempted to solve this problem?

Comment: Looks like duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40709488/all-possibilities-to-split-a-list-into-two-lists

Comment: @Pitirus 
Thanks, that's pretty much it.
except it has the same values repeated, just in different order

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.permutations()`

```
from itertools import permutations

# Get all permutations of [1, 2, 3]
perm = permutations([1, 2, 3])

# Print the obtained permutations
for i in list(perm):
    print (list(i[:1]),list(i[1:]))
    print (list(i[:2]),list(i[2:]))
```

output:

```
[1] [2, 3]
[1, 2] [3]
[1] [3, 2]
[1, 3] [2]
[2] [1, 3]
[2, 1] [3]
[2] [3, 1]
[2, 3] [1]
[3] [1, 2]
[3, 1] [2]
[3] [2, 1]
[3, 2] [1]
```