# how to divide a list to two lists and get all possible combinations

Tags: python, list, combinations

I have a list:

```
list1 = [1,2,3]
```

and I want to dived it to two list such that:

```
list2 = [[], [1], [2], [3], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
list3 = [[1,2,3], [2,3], [1, 3], [1, 2] ,[3], [2], [1], []]
```

I tried different loops but didn't get all combinations and I thought maybe there is an elegant way instead.

Comment: Check the `itertools` documentation for the `powerset` recipe.

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40709488/all-possibilities-to-split-a-list-into-two-lists and  https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-to-get-all-unique-combinations-of-two-lists/

Comment: list 2 is the powerset, list3 is the reverse of list 2.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps using itertools.

```
import itertools

list2 = []
for i in range(4):
    for j in itertools.combinations([1,2,3], r=i):
        list2.append( list(j) )
```

the output

```
[[], [1], [2], [3], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```